# Create child object with RestKit

Tags: ios6, ios7, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm new to RestKit but so far things seem to make sense, and I've setup some object mappings for a User object like so

```
+ (NSArray *) responseDecriptorsForEntityMapping:(RKEntityMapping *)entityMapping
{
    NSDictionary *mappings = @{
                               @"id": @"userID",
                               @"firstName": @"forename",
                               @"lastName": @"surname",
                               @"phoneNumber": @"phone",
                               @"emailId": @"email",
                               @"uri": @"uri",
                               };

    [entityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:mappings];
    [entityMapping setIdentificationAttributes:@[@"userID"]];
    // Setup response descriptors
    RKResponseDescriptor *getDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:entityMapping
                                                                                       method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                                  pathPattern:@"users/:userID"
                                                                                      keyPath:nil
                                                                                  statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

    return @[getDescriptor];
}
```

This is called from another class which sets the mappings for the object manager. This is working fine, and querying for a user object from the server works, so that's good.

What I want now is to create a child record. My `User` object contains a relationship to `devices`. What I want to now do, is create a new `Device` object and insert it into the `devices` set of the user.

Is there a way I can create a mapping that doesn't require me to specify the entire URL (i.e /users/:userID/devices) and have RestKit automatically calculate that?

If not, then that's ok, I can manually set that, but then second question, what is the general technique for creating the object, and putting it into the set? Would I just create the object as normal, and then once that's successfully created, simply use the normal core data method to add a new device, or can I configure RestKit to do this for me?

Comment: What JSON are you receiving? Have you looked at using routes with your path patterns?

Comment: I've had a brief look at routes but not in depth. The json I'd be receiving would be a simple object of the `Device` I'd just created

Comment: So are you creating this device and POSTing it to the server? In this case your device needs a `userID` property that RestKit can use to fill in the path pattern (usually via a route definition).

Comment: So I need to add a userID variable to the `Device` class? Does it need to be persisted in the core data store?

Comment: No, it can be transient - it just needs to be set when you call POST with the object. I haven't tried adding a keypath into the path pattern (to navigate a relationship to get the id) - could be worth a quick experiment...

Comment: it's not clear, do you have your "devices" in the  in the /users endpoint? (when retrieving user)

Comment: @Wain how would I then specify that the URL would need to use that transient property?

Comment: @thaold When fetching an individual user, no. The is just `/user/:userID`

Comment: RestKit uses sockit to process the path pattern and match against attribute names (hence the name must be `userID` in both the pattern and the class).

Comment: So would that involve me still specifying in my descriptors (or router) that a POST request to create a device would need the :userID in the URL? I still can't get it to figure that out automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You usually use an `RKRoute` to specify what path pattern to use when making a particular type (GET / POST / ...) of request with a specified class of object. The route examines the object to extract the appropriate parameters to substitute into the path pattern.

Once the route is configured, simply POST the object without supplying a path to the POST method. This causes the object manager to search for routes which match the type and class criteria so that it can build the required path.

When POSTing, you can create the object yourself and RestKit will both update it with the received response and save the update into the context.

Comment: getting confused again. So I've looked at the Router in more detail, and creating routes seems easy, but then how do I create the mappings? The only way I can see of actually adding mappings that I create is via the use of response descriptors, but I thought that using the router meant not needing the response descriptors?

Comment: router is for sending (generating the path to send to from a pattern). response descriptor is for examining the 'incoming' pattern and deciding which mapping to apply (thus what the destination class is).

Comment: router is effectively unconnected from the mapping process, it's entirely about path management.

Comment: Ahhh ok makes sense. What's the general way for creating a new object when using core data, as using [Class new] can't be used, but the old [Class object] from 0.1 was removed. Do I just use the standard core data approach of is there a new way?

Comment: Standard Core Data approach. You can treat the object as a stub to be filled in when you receive the response.